# installing ubuntu on to a pc without an os with a usb stick

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb-drive, bios

im trying to install ubuntu onto a pc i have built that does not currently have an os on it, i have followed the ubuntu instructions to make my usb bootable. in my bios i have the option to boot from four different USB-ZIP USB-HDD USB-FDD and USB-CDROM i have tried all but to no avail when i load up my pc without going to the bios it comes up with basic info about the flash drive and a bunch of stuff below, then below this it shows the drives it has tried to boot from and always comes up with boot error. I need some help.

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your USB drive is not bootable. Maybe try downloading the .iso again (make sure you get 32 or 64 bit depending on your hardware).

There are applications that make the drive bootable for you, Universal Pen Drive is a good one. Just copying a .zip or .iso onto a USB drive does not make it bootable.

After re downloading Ubuntu and making a bootable usb, hold down f12 (or option depending on your hardware) and it should pull up a list of bootable drives.

Another thing to check is the format of the USB drive before you try to put ubuntu on it, I'd use Fat 32.